# How to save Multiple Images from frontend form in ACF Repeater Field in my Post Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

There is my code in this code i insert data to post by frontend html form. i insert post title, description, featured image and ACF textfields. and Gallery images code only upload images to media library and update folder .. how to save this in raws in repeater field there is an screenshot where i save images please help me out

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOLCc.png)
this my form

```
  function process_post_creation() {
if(isset($_POST['jobs_nonce_field']) && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['jobs_nonce_field'], 'jobs_nonce')) {

    if(strlen(trim($_POST['job_title'])) < 1 || strlen(trim($_POST['job_desc'])) < 1) {
        $redirect = add_query_arg('post', 'failed', home_url($_POST['_wp_http_referer']));
    } else {        
        $job_info = array(
            'post_title' => esc_attr(strip_tags($_POST['job_title'])),
            'post_type' => 'news',
            'post_content' => esc_attr(strip_tags($_POST['job_desc'])),
            // 'post_category' => array($_POST['cat']), 
            'tags_input'    => array($tags),
            'post_status' => 'pending'
        );
        $job_id = wp_insert_post($job_info);

        if($job_id) {



require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );





$images= array();
  $pos_id=wp_insert_post( $my_post );
foreach($_FILES as $value){
   for ($i=0; $i <count($value['name']); $i++)



{ 
      $errors= array();
      $file_name = $value['name'][$i];
      $file_size = $value['size'][$i];
      $file_tmp = $value['tmp_name'][$i];
      $file_type = $value['type'][$i];
      $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$value['name'][$i])));
      
  if(empty($errors)==true) {
     $wordpress_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
     $profilepicture = $wordpress_upload_dir['path'].'/';
     move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $profilepicture.$file_name);
  }else{
     print_r($errors);
  }
  $file_name_and_location = $profilepicture.$file_name;
  $file_title_for_media_library = $value['name'][$i];
  $fildename = $value['name'][$i];
  $arr_file_type     = wp_check_filetype(basename($fildename));
  $uploaded_file_type = $arr_file_type['type'];
  $attachment = array(
     'post_mime_type' => $uploaded_file_type,
     'post_title' => addslashes($file_title_for_media_library),
     'post_content' => '',
     'post_status' => 'inherit',
     'post_parent' =>  0,
     'post_author' => get_current_user_id(),
  );        
  wp_read_image_metadata( $file_name_and_location );
  $attach_id     = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file_name_and_location,true,false);         
  $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attach_id,$file_name_and_location );
  wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
  $images[]= array("image" => $attach_id);


}
}
$field_key = "images_fildes";
update_field($field_key,$images,$pos_id);
add_row($field_key,$images,$pos_id);
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );
require( dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../../wp-load.php' );
set_post_thumbnail( $job_id, $thumbnail_id );
             
$upload = wp_upload_bits($_FILES["test"]["name"], null, file_get_contents($_FILES["test"]["tmp_name"]));
            $uploaddir = wp_upload_dir();
            $file = $_FILES["test"]["name"];
             $uploadfile = $uploaddir['path'] . '/' . basename( $file );

             move_uploaded_file( $file , $uploadfile );
             $filename = basename( $uploadfile );

             $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype(basename($filename), null );
         $attachment = array(
              'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
              'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', $filename),
              
          );
          $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $uploadfile );
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
        $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $uploadfile );
        wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
        update_post_meta($job_id,'_thumbnail_id',$attach_id);


        add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
        register_post_type( 'news', array(   
            'supports' => array('title', 'thumbnail'),
        ));

        update_post_meta($job_id, 'u_name', esc_attr(strip_tags($_POST['user_name'])));
        update_post_meta($job_id, 'u_email', esc_attr(strip_tags($_POST['user_email'])));
        update_post_meta($job_id, 'inq_email', esc_attr(strip_tags($_POST['inquiry_email'])));
            
        $redirect = add_query_arg('post', 'successfull', home_url($_POST['_wp_http_referer']));
            }
 }
        wp_redirect($redirect); exit;
    }
    }
    add_action('init', 'process_post_creation');
```

Answer (score 0):

Oops big mistake .. i'll got it..

I'll just change

update_field($field_key,$images,$job_id);
add_row($field_key,$images,$job_id);

Now my code is running successfully..